# Restaurant Maximum Profit using Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Its an assignment task,I have spend 2 days to come up with a solution but still having lots of confusion,however here I need to make few points clear. Following is the problem:

*Yuckdonald’s is considering opening a series of restaurant along QVH. n possible locations are along a straight line and the distances of these locations from the start of QVH are in miles and in increasing order **m1, m2, ...., mn**. The constraints are as follows:

1. At each location, Yuckdonald may open one restaurant and expected profit from opening a restaurant at location **i** is given as **pi**

2. Any two restaurants should be at least **k** miles apart, where **k** is a positive integer*

My solution:

```
public class RestaurantProblem {

    int[] Profit;
    int[] P;
    int[] L;
    int k;



    public RestaurantProblem(int[] L , int[] P, int k) {
        this.L = L;
        this.P = P;
        this.k = k;
        Profit = new int[L.length];
    }



    public int compute(int i){
        if(i==0)
            return 0;


        Profit[i]= P[i]+(L[i]-L[i-1]< k ? 0:compute(i-1));//if condition satisfies then adding previous otherwise zero
        if (Profit[i]<compute(i-1)){
                Profit[i] = compute(i-1);
            }
        return Profit[i];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] m = {0,5,10,15,19,25,28,29};
        int[] p = {0,10,4,61,21,13,19,15};
        int k = 5;

        RestaurantProblem rp = new RestaurantProblem(m, p ,k);
        rp.compute(m.length-1);
        for(int n : rp.Profit)
            System.out.println(n);

    }

}
```

This solution giving me 88 however if I exclude **(Restaurant at 25 with Profit 13)** and include **(Restaurant 28 with profit 19)** I can have 94 max...

point me if I am wrong or how can I achieve this if its true.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your codes are giving you wrong outputs or..?

Comment: actually i think my logic is not right so putting here to get some reviews from experts about the code as well as my understanding to this problem

Comment: I **didn't** down vote you but your post is likely to be closed by the users here..as this question seems to be more appropriate to be placed at code review. By the way, is your code giving you the correct output?

Comment: whats the downvote for? I am not asking the solution, only asking the missing thing or as I think right answer has to be 94

Comment: I don't think this deserver a downvote. I also don't think this belongs to CR as the user don't think (I haven't verified) he have the right answer.

Comment: I believe the recursion is incorrect; what is the exact semantics of `compute`? Also, dynamic programming would typically need no explicit recursion.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to identify 2 mistakes:

#### You are **not actually** using dynamic programming

, you are just storing the results in a data structure, which wouldn't be that bad for performance if the program worked the way you have written it and if you did only 1 recursive call.

However you do **at least 2** recursive calls. Therefore the program runs in `Ω(2^n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Dynamic programming usually works like this (pseudocode):

```
calculate(input) {
     if (value already calculated for input)
          return previously calculated value
     else
         calculate and store value for input and return result
}
```

You could do this by initializing the array elements to `-1` (or `0` if all profits are positive):

```
Profit = new int[L.length];
Arrays.fill(Profit, -1); // no need to do this, if you are using 0
```

```
public int compute(int i) {
    if (Profit[i] >= 0) { // modify the check, if you're using 0 for non-calculated values
        // reuse already calculated value
        return Profit[i];
    }
    ...
```

#### You assume the previous restaurant can only be build at the previous position

```
Profit[i] = P[i] + (L[i]-L[i-1]< k ? 0 : compute(i-1));
                                     ^
                  Just ignores all positions before i-1
```

Instead you should use the profit for the last position that is at least `k` miles away.

**Example**

```
k = 3
L   1   2   3   ...   100
P   5   5   5   ...     5
```

here `L[i] - L[i-1] < k` is true for all `i` and therefore the result will just be `P[99] = 5` but it should be `34 * 5 = 170`.

---

```
int[] lastPos;

public RestaurantProblem(int[] L, int[] P, int k) {
    this.L = L;
    this.P = P;
    this.k = k;
    Profit = new int[L.length];
    lastPos = new int[L.length];
    Arrays.fill(lastPos, -2);
    Arrays.fill(Profit, -1);
}

public int computeLastPos(int i) {
    if (i < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (lastPos[i] >= -1) {
        return lastPos[i];
    }
    int max = L[i] - k;
    int lastLastPos = computeLastPos(i - 1), temp;
    while ((temp = lastLastPos + 1) < i && L[temp] <= max) {
        lastLastPos++;
    }
    return lastPos[i] = lastLastPos;
}

public int compute(int i) {
    if (i < 0) {
        // no restaurants can be build before pos 0
        return 0;
    }
    if (Profit[i] >= 0) { // modify the check, if you're using 0 for non-calculated values
        // reuse already calculated value
        return Profit[i];
    }

    int profitNoRestaurant = compute(i - 1);
    if (P[i] <= 0) {
        // no profit can be gained by building this restaurant
        return Profit[i] = profitNoRestaurant;
    }

    return Profit[i] = Math.max(profitNoRestaurant, P[i] + compute(computeLastPos(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the prolem can be modelled with a two-dimensional state space, which I don't find in the presented implementation. For each `(i,j) in`{0,...,n-1}`times`{0,...,n-1}` let

```
profit(i,j) := the maximum profit attainable for selecting locations
               from {0,...,i} where the farthest location selected is
               no further than at position j
               (or minus infinity if no such solution exist)
```

and note that the recurrence relation

```
profit(i,j) = min{ p[i] + profit(i-1,lastpos(i)),
                          profit(i-1,j)
                 }
```

where `lastpos(i)` is the location which is farthest from the start, but no closer than `k` to position `i`; the first case above corresponds to selection location `i` into the solution while the second case corresponds to omitting location `j` in the solution. The overall solution can be obtained by evaluating `profit(n-1,n-1)`; the evaluation can be done either recursively or by filling a two-dimensional array in a bottom-up manner and returning its contents at `(n-1,n-1)`.